# Plot lines with ipython notebook + pandas

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following CSV:

```
Name,Concurrency,RPS
gunicorn,50,1000
gunicorn,150,1700
paster,50,100
paster,150,300
```

and I want to plot it so that X is "RPS"  and X is "Conccurency" and have a line for each "Name" (gunicorn, paster).

Would look something like this but with lines:

```
P = Paster
G = Gunicorn

200        P              G
100
50    P               G
0
     100     500    1000     2000
```

Answer (score 3):

Groupby it first and then plot it.

```
df.groupby('Name').plot('RPS', 'Concurrency')
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get it to be different colors?  and I can put a legend for the colors?